# How to add options menu on UIBarButtonItem in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add options menu over a UIBarButtonItem similar to what we see in android for material design. Similar to this

[image: Android OptionsMenu Material]

But I am stuck on how to add it over a UIBarButtonItem. Once clicked this menu should pop up anchored to that UIBarButtonItem and clicking outside should dismiss it. How to achieve the same?

```
class ABMenu: UIView {

    private var items:[ABMenuItem] = []
    private var tableView:UITableView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    convenience init(barButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem,items:[ABMenuItem]) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        self.items = items
        self.commonInit(barButtonItem: barButtonItem)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    private func commonInit(barButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem){
        self.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 200, height: self.items.count * 40)
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1.0, height: 1.0)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.8
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        
        tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableView.tableFooterView=UIView()
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(ABMenuItemCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "itemCell")
        
        self.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    
}

extension ABMenu:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath) as! ABMenuItemCell
        cell.setup(item:self.items[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.items[indexPath.row].onTap()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
}

class ABMenuItemCell:UITableViewCell {
    
    private var itemLabel:UILabel!
    
    func setup(item:ABMenuItem){
        for view in self.contentView.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        self.selectionStyle = .none
        
        itemLabel = UILabel()
        itemLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        itemLabel.backgroundColor = .white
        itemLabel.text = item.name
        itemLabel.textColor = .black
        itemLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        itemLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        itemLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(itemLabel)
        itemLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        itemLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        itemLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        itemLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    }
}


struct ABMenuItem {
    var name:String
    var onTap:(()->Void)
}
```

Comment: You could consider using a context menu with a bar button instead as it is simpler to implement: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/3601188-menu

Comment: Yes I could, but unfortunately, the whole UI design is kinda material looking, so can not use cupertino widgets that much.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a view for the menu, then setting the X and Y position relative to the button, and setting the view's `layer.zPosition = 1`

Below is an example of how this could be done. Note, I haven't tested this code yet. To implement clicking outside the menu to close it, you'll need to create a transparent view the size of the screen, positioned underneath the menu, add a UITapGestureRecognizer to it, and then link to an IBAction that removes the menu from the view.

```swift
// calculate location of menu
let openMenuButtonOrigin = openMenuButton.frame.origin
let menuWidth = 200
let menuHeight = 100
let menuX = openMenuButtonOrigin.x - menuWidth
let menuY = openMenuButtonOrigin.y + menuHeight

// create menu (this can be done in XIB/Storyboard file as well)
let menuView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: menuX, y: menuY, width: menuWidth, height: menuHeight))

// create menu option
let shareOption = UILabel()
shareOption.text = "Share"

shareOption.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuView).isActive = true
shareOption.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuView).isActive = true
shareOption.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuView).isActive = true
shareOption.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuView).isActive = true

menuView.addSubview(shareOption)

// add menu to view
menuView.layer.zPosition = 1
view.addSubview(menuView)
```